# Django: objects.raw() resulting query but not records

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I'm django newbie, I have one fundamental and one technical questions.

1. I'm using Postgres DB. I used psycopg2 connection/cursor for fetching the data, there was some delay while establishing a connection. I read that, ORM takes care of low level activities such as establishing a connection, etc. If I use django, ORM will takes care of connection challenge ?
   1.1. Can I expect same (low level activities) with raw() as well?
2. objects.raw(sql) returning Query but not records from the table.

I defined Student Model as below

```
class Student(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname
```

While creating the view,

def studentList(request):

```
#posts = Student.objects.all()  --> 1. working as expected (fetching all records firstname)

cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = "select * from api_student"
cursor.execute(sql)
posts = cursor.fetchone()      --> 2. returning entire record

#posts = Student.objects.raw(sql) --> 3. RETURNING SQL QUERY NOT RECORD FROM TABLE ???


print(posts)
return render(request, 'output.html', {'posts':posts})
```

output:

1. <QuerySet [<Student: Anil>]>
2. <RawQuerySet: select * from api_student>  --> **this is the challenge, did I miss any**
3. ('Anil', 'kumar')

Answer (score 1):

The **raw()** method takes a raw sql query, executes it, and returns a RawQuerySet instance. You can iterate on RawQuerySet like normal QuerySet and get objects.

```
sql = "select * from api_student"

student_qs = Student.objects.raw(sql)

for obj in student_qs:
    print(obj.pk, obj.firstname, obj.surname)
```